# Android Studio (3.1.4) Rendering Problems for Design + Blueprint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is a default starter project. No new codes were written yet. 
The image says it all:

[image]

**Android SDK Manager:**
[image]

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "chatchattan.nooguiquirks.com.chatchattan"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

I think I've downloaded the necessary SDK (28) for this. Even tried downgrading to API 24,25 to see if it changes anything but the Design and Blueprint rendering preview doesn't work.

Tried Solutions:

1. Make sure your Android SDK is updated to that of your build.gradle
2. Clean Project
3. Invalidate Cache/Restart
4. Use App Theme

STILL NOTHING!

Any bright ideas? : )

Comment: Do you have this problem in general or only with a specific project?

Comment: This is a newly/freshly created project. I'm expecting everything to work fine like a simple Hello World program. No formal codes were written yet.

Comment: please try this implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'

Comment: Okay I see. What version of the `com.android.support:appcompat` do you have implemented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Just Follow below step and good to go**

**1 Open design layout window tap on App Theme Top**

[image]

**2 Change theme to material light**

[image]

Comment: for some reason, this did it!!! Where is this documented? Do you know why this works?

Comment: man I facing this kind error last 2 weeks, I search on google or StackOverflow nothing work, just accidentally  changing the theme for my app it helps or from my perspective after updating SDK 27 to 28 I facing this error that's it

Comment: Android Studio is crazy - 90% SETUP, 10% ACTUAL CODING hahahahaha No wonder iphone dev beats em.

Comment: truly agree :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Add Base at the styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must change in module:app

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

with this :

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Then sync it

Answer (score 0):

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs at latest support library version

So solution change android support library version to `28.0.0-alpha1`

Or back to use 27 SDK Version